# Value inserted into MYSQL table differs from original value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm having the strangest problem with a value changing when I insert it to a MYSQL table.

This is for a Wordpress theme.

Here's the gist of the code:

```
$user_id = $_COOKIE['user-id'];
$wpdb->insert($custom_table,array('user_id'=>$user_id));
```

The type of the 'user_id' field of $custom_table is int(15).

I'm currently testing on myself. The user id stored in my cookie is 4022466561291. It's being stored in the database as 2147483647.

I've also tried various combinations of this setup:

```
$user_id = intval($_COOKIE['user-id']);
$wpdb->insert($custom_table,array('user_id'=>$user_id),array('%d'));
```

with the same results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because 2147483647 [is the maximum value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html) of a signed 4-byte `INT`.

You need to use a 8-byte `BIGINT` or - maybe more appropriate here - a `VARCHAR`.

The `(15)` after the `INT` is a bit misleading. It is a optional display length limitation only. It doesn't change the actual capacity of the data type.

Comment: Why would you consider `VARCHAR` as being more appropriate here?

Comment: @thejh the user ID looks like a random value chosen for security purposes rather than numbering (they hardly have trillions of users). Should the need arise to create even longer IDs in the future, even BIGINT will break at some point, a problem you don't get with a long VARCHAR

Comment: An anonymous user tried to add this as an edit, I figured it's worth mentioning: "While this is true, I had the same problem using $wpdb->insert with a %d in the $wpdb->prepare statement. My database was using BIGINT, but Wordpress when cleansing the input converted it to a regular int and would keep inserting the incorrect value. I changed it to a %s (leaving the column as a BIGINT) and it now stores the correct value".

Answer (score 1):

`int` will not hold that large of a value. You can try `bigint`. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

The maximum for `int` is 2147483647, try using `bigint`.

Answer (score 0):

From the MySql [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

> INT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
>
> A normal-size integer. The signed
>   range is -2147483648 to 2147483647.
>   The unsigned range is 0 to 4294967295.

The (15) on your INT is the suggested display width, and doesn't make an INT hold bigger numbers. You need a BIGINT.